# DynamoDB master and child tables as Publisher/ Subscriber in Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

I have two DynamoDB tables where one table is having records of Publishers (master table) and the other table is having records of Subscribers (child table).

I want to build a system where a change in the Publisher side leads to all Subscribers being notified. I have checked the documentation of AWS SNS, subscriber could be Lambda or SQS etc.

Is there any way I can make my child records as subscribers in DynamoDB?

So that whenever there is change in publisher records all the child records should be notified immediately.

Comment: *records* cannot be notified and they cannot subscribe to anything, that is not how anything works. You need to subscribe a lambda and then query the child table for the relevant data and notify someone based on that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on luk2302 completely valid comment:

There are a few **misconceptions** here:

- There is no direct integration between DynamoDB and SNS, so subscribing to individual items in a table doesn't work
- You can't manage the Subscribers for SNS outside of SNS, they need to be subscribed within SNS

The easiest way to implement the Publisher/Subscriber Pattern would indeed be SNS, but you can't just write to a DynamoDB table and integrate it.
If you want a DynamoDB based solution, I'd probably start like this.

There will be two tables:

- **Publishers** with a composite Primary Key of PK and SK and DynamoDB streams enabled
- **Subscribers** with a composite Primary Key of PK and SK

Also there is a Lambda function called **StreamProcessor** that has the **Publisher** table's stream as an input.

**Publishers** looks like this

| PK | SK | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `P#<id>` | `M#<id0>` | Some Message |
| `P#<id>` | `M#<id1>` | Some Message |
| `P#<id>` | `M#<id2>` | Some Message |
| `P#<id>` | `M#<id3>` | Some Message |

`P#<id>` with `<id>` being the id of the Publisher and the `M#<id0>` being a message ID.

**Subscribers** looks like this:

| PK | SK | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `P#<id>` | `S#<id0>` | test1@mail.com |
| `P#<id>` | `S#<id1>` | test2@mail.com |
| `P#<id>` | `S#<id2>` | test3@mail.com |
| `P#<id>` | `S#<id3>` | test4@mail.com |

`P#<id>` with `<id>` being the id of the Publisher and the `S#<id0>` being a subscription ID.

Now whenever there is a change in the Publisher table (e.g. a new message gets added to a publisher), the `StreamProcessor` Lambda will be called.
The `StreamProcessor` can then do something like this:

1. Extract the Publisher ID from the update record
2. Query the Subscribers table with `PK=P#<id>` to get a list of subscribers
3. For each result:
4. Determine the mode of contact
5. Send a message to the subscriber

Comment: Maurice, thanks for your detailed comment, I got your point, problem is, in StreamProcessor when I will query the subscriber table by Id it will fetch the list of Subscribers and I will have to iterate over list of subscribers, is it possible that I can get over this iteration? Because this iteration is creating problem for me because of long list of records and corrupt data.

Comment: No, if you want to build a DynamoDB based system you need to do that. An alternative would be a native SNS solution, but since all your data is in DynamoDB that's going to be a big change.